# magento using jquery with noconflict

Tags: jquery, magento, prototypejs, conflict

I'm using 2 jquery scripts for my Magento store. One of those scripts, a slider works perfectly and the other one doesnt work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();jQuery(function($){

function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
{
    // Disable autoscrolling if the user clicks the prev or next button.
    carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 0,
        wrap: 'circular',
        animation: 600,
        scroll: 6,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });

    $('.block_cart_header').hover(function(){
        $('.cart_add_items').fadeIn(700);
    },
    function(){
        $('.cart_add_items').fadeOut(700);
    });


});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.dropdown').selectbox();
}); });</script>
```

When I remove jQuery.noconflict(); both of the scripts work but the prototype script doesnt work.

This is the script that doesnt work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.dropdown').selectbox();}); });</script>
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: good question, this is what i get: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'attr'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to replace all `$(` into `jQuery(` and `$.` into `jQuery.` in jQuery related functions and plugins.

for example in your code replace

```
jQuery('.block_cart_header').hover(function(){
        jQuery('.cart_add_items').fadeIn(700);
    },
    function(){
        jQuery('.cart_add_items').fadeOut(700);
    });
```

## Extra information

You may change the order of library file initiating.
In page.xml change order as below

1. jquery.js
2. noconflict.js
3. prototype.js
   This will avoid the error in IE8.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The selectbox plugin is probably using the $ for it's JQuery calls. Change all the $ in the selectbox plugin to jQuery and it should work.

If not, please place a link to the used selectbox plugin.

Comment: this is not a solution, the plugins should work in noConflict mode

Comment: @Leon -> Try to replace all the occurences of $ with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the plugin that does not work is the problem. Leave the noConflict on, it is really needed for compatibility between the prototype and jQuery. Check if you are passing a correctly formatted HTML object to the plugin. Probably it expects an object with some specific attributes and those are not present.

Answer (score 0):

gowri solution worked for me , if the problem exist again then you need be confirm all the js file that have been used you may missing to check the js files and changed them as stated by "gowri" i.e :

```
replace all $( into jQuery( and $. into jQuery.
```