# Magento site slows with IE and gives script error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, magento, iframe, cross-browser

having issues with one of my clients magento frontend. The website works fine woth chrome but slows down when opening in IE( all versions) or FF. while with ff it is still working ok but the major issue is IE. the error I am getting is the "Stop running this script" A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly.
There is a video and a jquery flexislider running on that page and I am not sure if the iframe embed of video is causing the error. IF yes what is the best way to display a video on the page. 
Any help would be helpful
Thanks

Comment: probably same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310233/magento-using-jquery-with-noconflict/8310465#8310465

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem could be that Magento uses an outdated version of the Prototype javascript library and IE barfs on the old version. You either have to live with it or figure some way to upgrade Prototype. I have seen other messages on how to do that but they all said it was problematic.