# Configuring Royal Slider to work in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, slider

For the past few days I've been trying my best to get this [slider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/#banner-rotator) to work in Magento. However nothing seem to be working.

This is the documentation for it: http://dev.clickymedia.co.uk/web/documentation.html

So, what I did was add this to the head.phtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
    $('#banner-rotator').royalSlider({            
           imageAlignCenter:true,
           hideArrowOnLastSlide:true,
           slideSpacing:20
    });        
});
</script>
```

I then added the various css and js files in their respective folders and added this code to Magento's homepage CMS, design>custom design>Custom Layout Update XML>

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/royal-slider-8.1.min.js</script></action>
<action method="addCss"><script>css/royalslider.css</script></action>
<action method="addCss"><script>css/royalslider-skins/default/default.css</script
</action>
</reference>
```

lastly, in the homepage CMS, page content, I added this:

```
<div id="banner-rotator" class="royalSlider default">
<ul class="royalSlidesContainer">
<li class="royalSlide"> <img class="royalImage" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slider/banner1.png"}}" alt="banner1" width="1150" height="400" />
<div class="royalCaption" style="left: 58%; text-align: center; color: #33383e; width: 315px; top: 110px;">
<div class="royalCaptionItem" style="width: 100%;">Animated Blocks</div>
<div class="royalCaptionItem sgMidText" style="top: 35px; width: 100%;">with Custom Effects for Each Item</div>
<div class="royalCaptionItem sgSmallText " style="top: 70px; left: 96px;"><a class="tintButton non-draggable" href="[removed]void()">Button Example</a></div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="royalSlide"> <img class="royalImage" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slider/banner2.png"}}" alt="banner2" width="1150" height="400" />
<div class="royalCaption" style="left: 57%; top: 65px; color: #b93;">
<div class="royalCaptionItem" style="width: 280px;">Drag Navigation</div>
<div class="royalCaptionItem sgMidText" style="left: 120px; top: 35px; width: 200px;">with Mobile Support</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="royalSlide"> <img class="royalImage" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slider/banner3.png"}}" alt="banner3" width="1150" height="400" />
<div class="royalCaption" style="left: 40%; top: 130px; width: 300px; color: #eaeaed;">
<div class="royalCaptionItem " style="left: -320px;">Autoplay Slideshow</div>
<div class="royalCaptionItem sgMidText" style="left: -200px; top: 30px;">with Pause on Hover</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="royalSlide"> <img class="royalImage" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slider/banner4.png"}}" alt="banner4" width="1150" height="400" />
<div class="royalCaption" style="left: 40%; top: 120px; width: 400px; color: #4e4c39; text-align: center;">
<div class="royalCaptionItem " style="left: -320px; width: 100%;">Smart Lazy-Loading</div>
<div class="royalCaptionItem sgMidText" style="left: -320px; top: 35px; width: 100%;">Preloads Nearby Images After Current</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Although the slider is said to be a simple little JavaScript plugin, I am a newbie at this and have no success in adding to Magento. Please, if you have a solution for this, do help!

Comment: Are there errors in your javascript console?

Comment: Yes there is.

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent'
observeprototype.js:5653
Validation.initializevalidation.js:98
klassprototype.js:101
VarienForm.initializeform.js:35
klassprototype.js:101`  


and


`(anonymous function)beta:314
prototype.js:5734Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent'
fireprototype.js:5734
_methodizedprototype.js:438
fireContentLoadedEvent`

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me as though you are having a conflict between jQuery and prototype.

Have a look at the accepted answer for [magento using jquery with noconflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310233/magento-using-jquery-with-noconflict), I think you should check whether you need to do the same.

Comment: finally got it to work! realised it was conflicting with another script i had on the page. thanks for your replys :)

Comment: Might be a bit late, but I just noticed, maybe you could mark @CCBlackburn his answer as accepted :p

Answer (score 0):

The fault may be in your update xml part. Try this instead:

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>jquery/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>jquery/royal-slider-8.1.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/royalslider.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[]><!-->]]></if></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/royalslider-skins/default/default.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[]><!-->]]></if></action>
</reference>
```