# Magento jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery, magento

In my **head.phtml**, I have following declaration for getting a menu work.

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>jQuery_1205141001.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>Common_1205141001.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now, I am able to get the menu work, but because of this the **Add-to-cart** button on the details page is broken. If I remove the above references, the **Add-to-cart** button is restored. I looked at various question regarding the conflict between prototype.js and jquery and tried following things

1. First, I tried adding `jQuery.noConflict();` at the end of jquery-1.4.2.min.js, but it didn't worked. It also broke the menu
2. Second, I tried adding `jQuery.noConflict();` at the start of my query files, jQuery_1205141001.js and Common_1205141001.js. That too didn't helped.

Please tell me how to get both the things working. You can visit this [LINK](http://www.eyaas.com/products/toys-1/fp-bunny.html) for live test. Here you will see the menu working but the Add to cart is broken.

**NOTE**:- It has nothing to do with the Superfish.js and other errors shown in jquery debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>jQuery_1205141001.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>Common_1205141001.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict(); //Use no conflict here instead of js file
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

For details visit a link.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I tried adding '<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict(); //Use no conflict here instead of js file
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>` but this breaks the menu and also the add to cart button doesn't work

Comment: nopes....tried everything.....all my code is in those files......extra info: prototype.js is added before the avove references

Comment: $.noConflict(); -> jQuery.noConflict() and use $ -> jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @ShreeKhanal and MagePsycho. I am able to get things work. What i did is first copy paste your code in my **head.phtml** and then replaced **$.noConflict()** to **jQuery.noConflict**. And then i replaced the **$** occurence in my js files with **jQuery**. Please tell me if its the right way and it won't break anything. I am pretty dumb at javascript. Thanks once again to both of you

Comment: always welcome @Pankaj.Yap that is the best way to solve this problem.Happy coding P :)

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember having to call the different .js files/code in this order to get it to work correctly.

1. jquery.js
2. noconflict call
3. prototype.js

Have you given this a go?

It seems to be the answer in a couple of other questions:

[Weird Chrome prototype/jQuery conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833883/weird-chrome-prototype-jquery-conflict)

[magento using jquery with noconflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310233/magento-using-jquery-with-noconflict)

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving the file add two line breaks to jquery then

jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the 'no conflict' method but it didnt work for me.

In the end, I did NOT need it.

Here is how I solved the problem after 2 hours of tinkering:

Make sure that the conflicting javascript file that you are trying to introduce is the last javascript to be called in: /app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/YOURCHILDTHEME/template/page/html/head.phtml.

In my case, the troublesome file I was trying to introduce was: 'jquery-1.4.2.min.js'

I have a hunch that this may have conflicted with the default script: 'jquery-1.7.1.min.js'