# Add .js in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to add my own .js to a Magento project, but I can't do it...

I've followed the steps  [here](http://css-tricks.com/using-jquery-in-magneto/), but I still can't do it.

I did the following:

1. **Frontend:** Opened **page.xml** and inside the block: **block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head"**, I included my .js file: **lib/query.js**.
2. **Backend:** I modified **main.xml** like said [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/268482/), and I added the .js to the block named as *head*.

But nothing happens. The javascript seems to not be working. Any ideas on why, or any step that I need to follow?

I **EDIT THE QUESTION** because I found **a different problem...**:

I did everything as suggested in the Answers. And it didn't work. But I think it's because of the script.

When I go to firebut, I see these mistakes, that I don't know if they were at first:

[image: The mistake]

First mistake is located at **head.phtml**, when I make the call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

The second and the third one are located at the beginning of my .js files...

Any idea? Maybe solving this, will solve my other issue...

Comment: Are you putting your file in (root folder) /lib/query.js or /js/lib/query.js?

Comment: Second one... /js/lib/jquery.js. Is that correct?

Comment: Copy the url by viewing source for your script url (www.xyz/js/lib/jquery.js) and paste it into your browser address bar and check if load. Also check my code below for one way of doing jquery noconflict

Comment: @Sonhja: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310233/magento-using-jquery-with-noconflict/8310465#8310465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery: Creates a different alias for jQuery to use in the rest of the script.

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 // Do something with jQuery
 $j("div p").hide();
 //then use magento prototype with
 $("content").style.display = 'none';
```

See more http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Since it seem like you are add the same file to the admin and the frontend. Put your file in (root folder) /js/query.js (not /lib/query.js)

Add this to page.xml

```
 <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>query.js</script></action>
        ....
```

Add this to main.xml

```
<default>
    <block type="adminhtml/page" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page.phtml">
       <block type="adminhtml/page_head" name="head" as="head" template="page/head.phtml">
        <action method="addJs"><script>query.js</script></action>
        ....
```

It's not a wise idea to make changes to core files. Take a look on workaround for admin files
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/17306/

Comment: I copied the .js link, and it loads. I tried your code, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: If the file load that mean that the magento xml is working correctly. Did you fixed the jQuery noConflict() issue? Take a look at the url below the code for the example to use noConflixt() the way you have it or do it the way i suggest above. What error are you getting?

Comment: Yes, I'm making some advance... I solved the jQuery noConflict. That was a problem on the order I loaded the .js files. Right now I only have this one: TypeError: $(document).ready is not a function. Step by step I will arive! :D

Comment: With the way above you would do  $j(document).ready()... with your way jQuery.noConflict()(function(){
     $(document).ready()
});

Comment: It still says jQuery is not defined... :(( Aggg!

Comment: I will make your answer as good. I think it will someday work... :P

Comment: What I normally do is append 'var $j = jQuery.noConflict();' to the end of my jquery.js file

Answer (score 1):

1) Have you deleted the cache and session?: http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_clear_the_cache_in_Magento.html

2) Double check the page source in your web browser. The file might be included correctly already, but may be your javascript file itself is the problem.

Comment: I think you're right. I think my javascript is wrong. Could yo please check the edit and see if you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the 'block type="page/html_head" ' insert following line

```
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/query.js</script></action>
```

Also put your query.js file  at   "magento-root-direcory/js/lib/query.js" location.
And of course do the reindexing and delete your cache.

Comment: I did so, but I think my problem is a different one... Why do you think that mistakes appear?