# Magento Prototype and third party jquery files conflicting

Tags: jquery, prototype, magento-1.7

I need to use jquery in my Magento store. I've managed to let both prototype and jquery of my extension work alongside. But the problem is I am using two third party extensions. Both have their own jquery files to include. Now prototype of Magento and two additional jquery files are making a mess of my store. Is there any way to use one jquery file for both extensions. I have tried using the latest jquery version but neither extension works with that version. I am out of options and ideas here. Can anyone tell me how can i make this work?

I tried removing the script blocks. But it generates more errors. I have one extension that displays product images in a lightbox from product list page. This extension uses **jquery-1.7.2.min.** version. The other is a call for price extension which uses **jQuery v1.4.2** version. I removed the one from call for price extension's xml and added a **jQuery v1.8.2** version in page.xml. So both the extensions can use it. It now generates these errors:

```
TypeError: $(document).ready is not a function
$(document).ready(function() {
```

This code is written in my list.phtml file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var curUrl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts/index/reseturl/') ?>";

    $("#selCat").change(function(){ 
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",    
        data: "catUrl=" + $("#selCat").val(),
        url: curUrl,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response){
            //alert(response);
            window.location.replace(response);
          }   
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: try thid answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310233/magento-using-jquery-with-noconflict/8310465#8310465

Comment: open your extension layout xml file and remove addscript block from xml.

Comment: Removing the script block from xml file generates more errors :(

Comment: Update your question with what are the scripts you using in order and what error you getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I've found a solution for my problem for now. I combined the two jquery files of my two third party extensions into one so now for both of them I include only one file. There was still the conflict between that file and the default prototype.js. So what i did was added

```
$.noConflict();
```

on the top of my product view file **view.phtml** which released the use of **$** from the jquery code to prototype. And all is working as it should now. Thanks for all who replied to me and I hope my solution works for someone else.